# form control does not display centered

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell

When I create a form and add a control, I set the size and location to be centered on the form.  Instead I get something that is offset to the right and down.

What is causing this offset?!

```bsh
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing')

# Main form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(400,500)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$form.SizeGripStyle = 'Hide'
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.ShowInTaskbar = $true
$form.Text = 'I wont display right.'

#control
$mainPanel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$mainPanel.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Top
$mainPanel.Size = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(($form.Width - 50),($form.Height - 50))
$mainPanel.Location = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(25,25)
$mainPanel.AutoScroll = $true
$mainPanel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Black
$form.Controls.Add($mainPanel)

$form.BringToFront()
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful

Comment: A Control is placed on the Form's ClientArea. You're considering the whole size of the Form, including Caption and Borders. Use the Form's ClientRectangle (or ClientSize) measure to determine a Control's Location.

Comment: @CaiusJard added picture for you, even though this was already answered, in case anyone following behind us is curious.

Comment: also thank you to everyone for the quick replies!  I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form size and Work-space (client) Area is different.

- Form size includes border size and title bar also.
- Client Area is actual space where you put your controls ( location 0,0 ).

change only one line in your code to get desire output :

> $mainPanel.Size = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(($form.ClientSize.Width -
>   50),($form.ClientSize.Height - 50))

Comment: can you set the main form by clientsize?  is there a property that shows the difference between clientsize & size?

Comment: Clientsize is always less then form size. you can set main for size by calculating the client size, so at the end you get desired clientsize..like frm.size.width =400; diff = frm.size.width - frm.cz.width ; frm.size.width += diff ; and same way you can calculate the height of your form

Comment: The  client size is depends on theme/resolution/ form border style etc.. so we have to calculate the form size from the client size..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following adjustment:

```
$mainPanel.Size = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(($form.ClientSize.Width - 50),($form.ClientSize.Height - 50))
```